# not able to convert file read() to an integer

Tags: python

I have a simple file which contains exactly one integer. This integer is an epoch timestamp value.

```
ts_f = open('latest_ts','r')
pattern = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S NZDT %Y'
tmp = ts_f.read()


//Do some processing to update the timestamp value.

ts_f.close()

ts_f = open('latest_ts','w+')
ts_f.write(latest_ts_epoch)
ts_f.close()
```

Since both of these are integer values and read returns a string, I tried to convert `tmp` to an interger as `int(tmp)`.It does not allow me to convert tmp to an integer and gives the error
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

Comment: is that exactly how you cast?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - yes.What is wrong with it?

Comment: I am going to assume that you have a string in your tmp value, but I can only assume because you may need to show us how you process value you are feeding through

Comment: Can you provide an example output of printing tmp?

Comment: Python comment is `#` not `//`. Not that it makes much difference :-)

Comment: Your file probably starts with a BOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See added line below, your file starts with a BOM which needs to be decoded first.

```
ts_f = open('latest_ts','r')
pattern = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S NZDT %Y'
tmp = ts_f.read()

tmp = tmp.decode("utf-8-sig")

ts_f.close()

ts_f = open('latest_ts','w+')
ts_f.write(latest_ts_epoch)
ts_f.close()
```